# iCloud Hacked and trusted number changed - is there anything I can do?

Tags: iphone, icloud, security, sim

*Note: This might be more of a rant than a question, but I'd still appreciate advice.*

I have a dual SIM phone. All of a sudden, the eSIM (personal line) kept getting calls on loop from a number saying that this is Apple and that someone logged into my account.

A few minutes later, I'm signed out of all my iCloud Devices. I tried to sign back in, and the password stopped working, and the trusted number was changed.

Then, my phone was remotely wiped right in front of me and it was set up as a new phone, without the ability to restore from iCloud Backups since my iCloud account was no longer accessible.

When I set up the phone as a new phone, I only had one SIM (physical SIM) and no eSIM registered anymore on the phone.

My theory of what's happened is they SIM swapped my personal phone line and somehow got into my Apple ID (It was a fairly strong password, unless it got leaked somehow), and used access to my personal number to gain access to my iCloud. I got access to my phone line a few hours later by going back to AT&T and creating a new eSIM. Of course, AT&T has no logs or historical info showing a new device has been changed or what the IMEI even was.

Apple repeatedly says they can't do anything to restore access to my iCloud account because my trusted number has been changed. I understand that perhaps due to end-to-end encryption and/or privacy components here, even Apple can't do something, but I just find it so ridiculous that even though I own the email and the username, nothing can be done.

I saw an [article with something like this happening, though I don't know if it ended up going anywhere](https://www.newsweek.com/woman-says-apple-failed-help-hacked-account-until-her-plea-went-viral-1673661).

Has anyone either:

1. Dealt with this before, and has some advice for me?
2. Knows anything more about how to escalate a situation like this.

Comment: There is something missing here.  Your trusted *device* like your iPhone is what authenticates you.  To access your iCloud account via your trusted device, you need either your iPhone passcode or iCloud password. None of this is attached to a SIM. Dis you turn on 2FA?

Comment: I had 2FA on, yes. In the past, I've had to enter 6 digit codes entered when I log into my accounts.

I'm not saying that just SIM swapping let the hacker get into my iCloud. I'm not sure what benefit SIM swapping really did for the hacker. I think the hacker was able to get into a bank account due to it.

Comment: That isn”t sent over SMS,  your SIM only authenticates you to a cell network, it”s unrelated Apple. It”s sent over encrypted connection.  If someone was able to take over your account with these protections enabled, you had to have exposed a TON of info that”s supposed to be secured.  They likely had full access to your email account and possibly even your computer.

Comment: "this is Apple and that someone logged into my *account."* This is the first fishy bit. Apple doesn't do that - what did you tell them?

Comment: I agree with @Tetsujin, Apple won't phone you like that. I phoned them and they check *SO* much before even simple things (like sorting an iMac screen repair). So change ALL the passwords on your bank stuff - even stop the accounts and get new cards, pins etc sent.

Comment: I agree. But I didn’t give any info on the call. It was not a real person, it was a bot. It just said “unauthorized access detected to your Apple ID account”. They could have spoofed the Apple support number as it was a 800 number.